# select2 dropdownAutoWidth property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Was doing some research, and discovered this property in the select2 jQuery plugin. If my assumption is correct the `dropdownAutoWidth` property will increase the size of the select2 dropdown to whatever is the widest item in the list. Peachy, so I instantiate the plugin on an element

```
$('.cp_accessory.interface_dropdown.skin_customizer').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: 99999,
  dropdownCssClass: 'solo_dropdown',
  dropdownAutoWidth : true
});
```

But unfortunately the width is still as short as the first item when activating the dropdown.
[image: dropdown fail]

As a sidenote, that `solo_dropdown` class I added does not change widths anywhere. So I don't *think* that would be the problem. Any help or insight would be appreciated

Comment: I'd create a JSFiddle of the base HTML and the plugin included and I can help you more :)

Comment: @benhowdle89 Didn't include styling because it doesn't even work on default styling, but here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/SDFvG/

Answer (score 0):

use latest select2 from github repo's. i've updated your jsfiddle and now seems to be it's okay

http://jsfiddle.net/SDFvG/5/

CSS

```
.select2-drop-active{
border-top:1px solid #5897fb !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
$('.cp_accessory.interface_dropdown.skin_customizer').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: 99999,
    dropdownCssClass: 'solo_dropdown',
    dropdownAutoWidth : 'auto'
});
```

Below is my code

```
$("#selectTagId").select2({
    data: data,
    dropdownAutoWidth: "auto"
});
```